# Redirect has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: azure, cors, tomcat8

I am working on Azure AD interactive login from my webapp. When a user logs in to my site he is redirected to the Azure login page, authenticated and returned to my site. This process involves a request to login.windows.net which redirects my browser to  login.microsoftonline.com(which does the authentication).
However I am getting a cors issue which states that redirect to login.microsoftonline.com has been blocked doe to no "Access Control Allow Origin" header from the requested source. I know it is possible to add this header when the requested resource is in my webapp, but in this case its not. My question is if login.microsoftonline.com doesn't return the header which causes this, how can I handle this issue from my webapp? Below is the error on my browser console.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://login.windows.net//oauth2/authorize?…......-4129-adea-
>   ccdcbdeaa80e&nonce=c962fb8a-3c8c-4dec-9fbc-4f2fb8fcfde1.  Redirect
>   from
>   'https://login.windows.net//oauth2/authorize?…......-4129-adea-ccdcbdeaa80e&nonce=c962fb8a-3c8c-4dec-9fbc-4f2fb8fcfde1'
>   to
>   'https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/au….......-4129-adea-ccdcbdeaa80e&nonce=c962fb8a-3c8c-4dec-9fbc-4f2fb8fcfde1'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource.  Origin 'https://my_host'
>   is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Couldn't you just redirect them right away to login.microsoftonline.com?

Comment: @juunas I tried what you said but the issue is still there. Got the below error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_name>/oauth2/au…......-4d58-8cb3-f0c58587c42d&nonce=beb38902-6be9-4a8c-8464-8eb96af9871b. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://my_host' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: But you should not be doing an XHR against the authorize endpoint. You should be doing a redirect.

Comment: @juunas how does that make a difference?

Comment: The first is an AJAX call done from the current domain which is bound by CORS rules. The second actually tells the browser to set the location in the address bar to the given URL and go there. Domain changes and no CORS is involved. The authorize endpoint does not take cross-domain requests.

Comment: @juunas If redirects dont involve CORS then my first approach mentioned in the question should be working.
 I doubt the last sentence of your comment because according to this example (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect) it does take cross-domain requests. I have copied the code from the same location.

Comment: I ran that sample successfully, there's no AJAX/CORS calls there. So `login.windows.net` just redirects to `login.microsoftonline.com` and the flow completes normally. What have you changed in that sample to get that error?

Comment: @juunas even I ran the sample and didn't get the error. Only when I copied the code into my custom webapp and ran is when I am getting this error. I don't see any difference in the request and response to login.windows.net in the 2 apps except for the fact that my webapp is sending an additional "Origin" header in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to bypass this issue by passing the redirect url to a form action and triggering the submit using Javascript instead of directly redirecting to the url. CORS check is not done when the request comes from a form submit.

Comment: Can you please share your code - how did you go about it?